# Postback redirect through add_action is not triggered

Tags: functions, redirect, actions, forms

template:

```
<form action="<?php echo esc_url( admin_url('admin-post.php')); ?>" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="boo" id="boo" required>
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="foo">
</form>
```

I have add the hook in theme functions.php and `moo` is registered:

```
add_action( 'admin_post_foo', 'moo' );
add_action( 'admin_post_nopriv_foo', 'moo' );
function moo() {
    wp_safe_redirect(
        esc_url(
            site_url( 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/?page_id=5' )
        )
    );
}
```

and still after post it hangs on `admin_post.php`

I don't have debug and I'm clueless of whether the hook is invoked so any idea of how to determine that as well?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your site's address is `example.com`. When you want to redirect to `example.com/page/subpage` you should use `site_url('/page/subpage')`.

I assume the WordPress address is `http://127.0.0.1:8000`. You have in your code
`site_url( 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/?page_id=5' )` and it will be converted to this address:  `http://127.0.0.1:8000http://127.0.0.1:8000/?page_id=5`.

Try using this redirection:

```
wp_safe_redirect( site_url( '/?page_id=5' ) );
```

---

Second issue, if you'll take a look at [code reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_safe_redirect), you will find there:

> *wp_safe_redirect()* does not exit automatically and should almost always be followed by exit.

Comment: Indeed but I didn't have redirection at all and it turns out that the `action` value doesn't trigger the event if too short string. Mine was 2 letter although in the example here is `foo`. 10x anyway. Would have gave  you +1 but my rating is too low so i can't vote.

Comment: Did you try to replace `wp_redirect()` to `echo "text from moo() function"; die();` in the function `moo()` to check whether function will be called and you will see message? @BatMan

Comment: `action` value may be even one char and it will work.